# Blackberry IT policy checking

Tags: blackberry

Does anybody know how to check BES IT policy from the device side?
I mean, there is an API for it in net.rim.device.api.itpolicy.ITPolicy like     ITPolicy.getBoolean(String name, boolean defaultValue), but what "name" should I use to check, for example, "Disable GPS" rule?
It is submitted to the device and observable in Options > Security > Security Status Information, but this method always returns defaultValue, even for "Disable_GPS" and "DisableGPS".

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. It happens that `ITPolicy` class is intended only to retrieve custom it policies defined by the admin in the BES server, not the regular ones like GPS and the like. For example, a custom policy for your app, like "doihaveadminaccess", the BES admin creates a new policy and pushes it to your BB, then your app can get the BES setting for it.

However, the class also allows you to retrieve the built in BES policies, but RIM never published the IDs in their docs. the only way to retrieve the ID (string or int) is hacking, I guess.